# Getting null value from standard getter method of sObject

Tags: apex, unit-test, sobject, boolean

I am stuck in a very strange situation. I have one custom object (test_Boolean__c) and a field of **checkbox** type (check_Boolean__c) whose default value is true.

Now this is what I did :-
Created a record of test_Boolean__c object in a **test method.**

And run a code

```
test_Boolean__c obj = new test_Boolean__c();
insert obj;
Boolean x1 = obj.check_Boolean__c; // => true
Boolean x2 = (Boolean) obj.get('check_Boolean__c'); // => null
```

I am getting two different value of check_Boolean__c field.

Not getting any solution of it. I want same behavior for `Boolean x2 = obj.get('check_Boolean__c');` too

Comment: The `get` method will return the same value or throw an "Invalid field" exception if the name is wrong. As `Boolean x2 = obj.get('check_Boolean__c');` won't compile unless you include a Boolean cast, I suspect you may be reaching the wrong conclusion in your testing.

Comment: What happens if you re-query the values from the database?  I vaguely recall something about the default values being database level, so perhaps they're not available until you query the record.

Comment: Yeah, this is what i tried minutes ago. 
Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the workaround for this

```
test_Boolean__c obj = new test_Boolean__c();
insert obj;
Boolean x1 = obj.check_Boolean__c; // => true
Boolean x2 = (Boolean) obj.get('check_Boolean__c'); // => null
```

Using this will always give a null value for standard getter method.

Use like this for getting same behavior of fetching field by using both ways.

```
test_Boolean__c obj = new test_Boolean__c();
insert obj;
obj = [select check_Boolean__c from test_Boolean__c limit 1];
Boolean x1 = obj.check_Boolean__c; // => true
Boolean x2 = (Boolean) obj.get('check_Boolean__c'); // => true
```

Means you need to reload the obj for this.

Answer (score 3):

To illustrate what Keith mentioned in his comment, try running your above code in the execute anonymous window. Using a checkbox field on Account, I simulated what you are trying to do, with and without casting as Keith mentioned and with casting it definitely should work as you believe it should.

```
Account acctTrue = [select Match_Billing_Address__c from Account WHERE Match_Billing_Address__c = true limit 1];
Account acctFalse = [select Match_Billing_Address__c from Account WHERE Match_Billing_Address__c = false limit 1];
Boolean x1 = acctTrue.Match_Billing_Address__c; // => true
Boolean x2 = acctTrue.get('Match_Billing_Address__c'); // => null
Boolean x3 = acctFalse.Match_Billing_Address__c; // => true
Boolean x4 = acctFalse.get('Match_Billing_Address__c'); // => null

System.assertEquals(x1, x2);
System.assertEquals(x3, x4);

System.debug('x1:' + x1 + ' x2:' + x2 + ' x3:' + x3 + ' x4:' + x4);
```

The above results in the error when attempted to run:
[image: Error]

However, after adding boolean casts to both lines 4 and 6:

```
Account acctTrue = [select Match_Billing_Address__c from Account WHERE Match_Billing_Address__c = true limit 1];
Account acctFalse = [select Match_Billing_Address__c from Account WHERE Match_Billing_Address__c = false limit 1];
Boolean x1 = acctTrue.Match_Billing_Address__c; // => true
Boolean x2 = (Boolean)acctTrue.get('Match_Billing_Address__c'); // => null
Boolean x3 = acctFalse.Match_Billing_Address__c; // => true
Boolean x4 = (Boolean)acctFalse.get('Match_Billing_Address__c'); // => null

System.assertEquals(x1, x2);
System.assertEquals(x3, x4);

System.debug('x1:' + x1 + ' x2:' + x2 + ' x3:' + x3 + ' x4:' + x4);
```

You can see the results in the debug log and the asserts passed.
[image: debug log]

Update based on the comment, I believe what you need to do in your test class is load the defaults for the field, the following from the [docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_Schema_SObjectType.htm#apex_Schema_SObjectType_newSObject_2), should help you resolve that issue:
newSObject(recordTypeId, loadDefaults)

Constructs a new sObject of this type, and optionally, of the specified record type ID and with default custom field values.
Signature

> public sObject newSObject(ID recordTypeId, Boolean loadDefaults)
>
> Parameters
>
> recordTypeId
>
> Type: ID
>
> Specifies the record type ID of the sObject to create. If no record
>   type exists for this sObject, use null. If the sObject has record
>   types and you specify null, the default record type is used.
>
> loadDefaults
>
> Type: Boolean
>
> Specifies whether to populate custom fields with their predefined
>   default values (true) or not (false).
>
> Return Value
>
> Type: sObject
>
> Usage
>
> For required fields that have no default values, make sure to provide
>   a value before inserting the new sObject. Otherwise, the insertion
>   results in an error. An example is the Account Name field or a
>   master-detail relationship field.
>
> Since picklists and multi-select picklists can have default values
>   specified per record type, this method populates the default value
>   corresponding to the record type specified.
>
> If fields have no predefined default values and the loadDefaults
>   argument is true, this method creates the sObject with field values of
>   null.
>
> If the loadDefaults argument is false, this method creates the sObject
>   with field values of null.
>
> This method populates read-only custom fields of the new sObject with
>   default values. You can then insert the new sObject with the read-only
>   fields, even though these fields cannot be edited after they’re
>   inserted.
>
> If a custom field is marked as unique and also provides a default
>   value, inserting more than one new sObject will cause a run-time
>   exception because of duplicate field values.
>   [image: execute anonymous example]

Comment: Hello Jenny
Thanks for your help, but problem is a bit different.
I have a check box field, whose value is by default true. And I am doing all this stuff in a test class with seeAllData=false. so I am getting null value while using getter method.

Comment: Sorry for not mention test method.

Comment: @VivekMalpani ok, I updated my answer based on what I think your stating your issue to be.